# Create a post table with the userID added to the post table and postID added automatically to the image table in sequlize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I want to create a post creation function with nodejs and postgresql using sequelize. models include user tables, post tables, and images. I don't know how to create foreign key links for tables so when a user logs in and creates a post, it will add user ids to the post table as well as post ids to the image table, who can help me Can I draw a schema? and how to create posts?

// migration

```
// user
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Users', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      firstName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      lastName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      username: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      phone: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      gender: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Users');
  }
};
```

```
// post
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Posts', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      userID: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: 'Users',
          key: 'id'
        }
      },
      description: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT
      },
      like: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        defaultValue: 0
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Posts');
  }
};
```

```
// image
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Images', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      postID: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: 'Posts',
          key: 'id'
        }
      },
      urlImage: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Images');
  }
};
```

// models

```
// user
use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
    lastName: DataTypes.STRING,
    username: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    phone: DataTypes.STRING,
    gender: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});
  User.associate = function(models) {
    User.hasMany(models.Post, {refeignKey: 'userID'})
    User.hasMany(models.Comment, {refeignKey: 'userID'})
    User.hasMany(models.Follow, {refeignKey: 'userID'})
    User.hasMany(models.Follow, {refeignKey: 'userID_follow'})
  };
  return User;
};
```

```
//post
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Post = sequelize.define('Post', {
    description: DataTypes.STRING,
    like: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {});
  Post.associate = function(models) {
    Post.belongsTo(models.User, {refeignKey: 'userID'})
    Post.hasOne(models.Image, {refeignKey: 'postID'})
    Post.hasOne(models.Comment, {refeignKey: 'postID'})
  };
  return Post;
};
```

```
//image
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Image = sequelize.define('Image', {
    urlImage: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});
  Image.associate = function(models) {
    Image.belongsTo(models.Post, {refeignKey: 'postID'})
  };
  return Image;
};
```

// routers

```
const result = await Post.create({
            description: postInfo.description,
            Image: {
            urlImage: postInfo.urlImage
            }
            },{
               include: Image
            })
```

error : null value in column \"userID\" violates not-null constraint